# How to escape $ symbol in groovy when writing code in output block of a rule table in camunda dmn

Tags: groovy, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have to write perl scripts in Camunda DMN in output block

As perl script uses $ symbol for defining scalars.
At the same time Camunda' DMN written in Groovy will try to resolve $ symbol but i do not want it to get resolved as i wanted it to be present as is so that perl understads it as scalar

So how to escape $ symbol in DMN of Camunda.

I have tried \$ and \$ but didn't work.

```
execPerl(profile, """ #Test . $sum=0;    print "$sum";""", logStd, logErr);
```

I want camunda to not resolve $sum. Because i am passing this as perl command

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes `'` in place of `"""`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear the `execPerl` command and its parameters, but if you want to get a string result which value is `execPerl(profile, """ #Test . $sum=0;    print "$sum";""", logStd, logErr);` from the output of DMN, I think you can try `"execPerl(profile, \"\"\"#Test . $sum=0;    print \"$sum\");\"\"\", logStd, logErr);"`. I don't think there's anything about how to escape the `$`.

There's a code segment of DMN's xml for your reference:

```
<outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_01gq7wg">
      <text>"execPerl(profile, \"\"\"#Test . $sum=0;    print \"$sum\");\"\"\", logStd, logErr);"</text>
</outputEntry>
```